# What happens to MDBottomAppBar (Kivymd)?

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I had a screen with a bottomAppbar working, now when I opened it the MDBottomAppbar color was there without the widget on it.
I tried to recreate another one, but the same thing happened. It doesn't give any code error.
But The MDTopAppBar works perfectly alone.
[My kivy file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5fB2.png)

Kivy code:

```
<EkzampBanner@Screen>
    MDBanner:
        id:banner
        text:["Yon sel liyn teks san aksyon."]
        over_widget:scroll
        vertical_pad:toolbar.height


    MDTopAppBar:
        id:toolbar
        title:"My banner for me!"
        md_bg_color:.3,.3,.4,.1
        elevation:20
        left_action_items:[["menu",lambda x:app.change_items()]]
        right_action_items:[["dots-vertical",lambda x:app.change_items()]]
        pos_hint: {'top':1}    
    MDBottomAppBar:
        MDTopAppBar:
            id:bottom_app_bar
            elevation:20
            title:"My Bottom Bar!"
            icon:"plus-circle"
            type:"bottom"
            icon_color: 1, 0, .4, .1
            md_bg_bottom_color: "orange"
            left_action_items:[["menu",lambda x:app.chanje_mounyo()]]
            
            right_action_items:[["gmail", lambda x:app.chanje_mounyo()],["bookmark", lambda x:None],["instagram", lambda x:None]]
    ScrollView:
        id:scroll
        size_hint_y:None
        height:Window.height - toolbar.height

        MDGridLayout:
            id:box
            adaptive_height:True
            cols:1
            padding:"10dp"
            spacing:"10dp"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "ThreeLineBanner"
                on_release:
                    banner.type = "three-line"
                    banner.text = \
                    [\
                    "Three line string text example with two actions.", \
                    "This is the second line of the banner message,", \
                    "and this is the third line of the banner message.",
                    ]
                    banner.left_action = ["CANCEL", lambda x: None]
                    banner.right_action = ["CLOSE", lambda x: banner.hide()]
                    banner.show()
            
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "TwoLineIconBanner"
                on_release:
                    banner.type = "two-line-icon"
                    banner.text = \
                    [\
                    "One line string text example with two actions.", \
                    "This is the second line of the banner message.", \
                    ]
                    banner.left_action = ["CANCEL", lambda x: None]
                    banner.right_action = ["CLOSE", lambda x: banner.hide()]
                    banner.show()

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "OneLineIconBanner"
                on_release:
                    banner.type = "one-line-icon"
                    banner.text = ["One line string text example with two actions."]
                    banner.left_action = ["CANCEL", lambda x: None]
                    banner.right_action = ["CLOSE", lambda x: banner.hide()]
                    banner.show()

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Banner without actions"
                on_release:
                    banner.type = "one-line-icon"
                    banner.text = ["One line string text example without actions."]
                    banner.left_action = []
                    banner.right_action = []
                    banner.show()

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Banner with one actions"
                on_release:
                    banner.type = "one-line-icon"
                    banner.text = ["One line string text example without actions."]
                    banner.left_action = []
                    banner.right_action = ["CLOSE", lambda x: banner.hide()]
                    banner.show()
```

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

class EkzampBanner(MDScreen):
pass

class MyBanner(MDApp):
    def change_items(self):
        self.root.ids.bottom_app_bar.right_action_items=\[\["whatsapp"\],\["facebook"\],\["twitter"\]\]
        self.root.ids.bottom_app_bar.md_bg_bottom_color="lightgray"
        self.root.ids.bottom_app_bar.icon="account-circle"
        self.root.ids.toolbar.md_bg_color= "#FFA500"
        self.root.ids.bottom_app_bar.icon_color=\[0, 0, 1, 1\]

   def chanje_mounyo(self):
        self.root.ids.bottom_app_bar.md_bg_bottom_color="orange"
        self.root.ids.bottom_app_bar.icon="account-circle"
        self.root.ids.toolbar.md_bg_color= [.3,.3,.4,.1]
        self.root.ids.bottom_app_bar.icon_color=[1, 0, .4, .1]
        
    
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('mybanner.kv')
        return EkzampBanner()

if __name__=='__main__':
    MyBanner().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MDBottomNavigation:

    MDBottomNavigationItem:
        text: "2d"
        name: "2D screen"
        icon: "square-outline"
        [Contents]
        
    MDBottomNavigationItem:
        text: "2d"
        name: "2D screen"
        icon: "square-outline"
        [Contents]
```

Try this